# Android Studio vim dark theme - Unable to edit some colors

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ide, themes

I downloaded Vim Dark [here](https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes). I prefer change all grey text to white, but i stuck on Local variable, Constructor declaration, ...etc because there's no colour block to click.

[image]

My platform is Fedora 21 and Android Studio 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the answer.

I have to change the color on *General -> Text -> Default Text*.
[image]

And also *General -> Errors and Warnings -> Unused symbol*. For unknown reason, you have to Click "Apply"/"OK" to take effect on Java section preview.
[image]